# Github error when pulling and pushing

Tags: github, aptana

I have been working on github for a while now, I had a problem with my msys-1.0.dll file, I fixed the problem and everything is working fine but I have a problem with this statement "Received disconnect from 192.33.232.526: 11: Bye Bye" it appears everytime I do a gitpull it makes my pc take more time to do a the pull. How can I solve this problem :Received disconnect from 192.34.252.665: 11: Bye Bye

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this as the best solution use terminal it will be much easier, and faster to pull and push or do your git commands there or generate a new ssh key by doing that it will take out that Received disconnect from 192.34.252.665: 11: Bye Bye message and refreshing your current repository